# How to get accessToken from ReactFire/Firebase in class component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, reactfire, react-firebase-hooks

I need the firebase accessToken in the ErrorBoundary class component, but ReactFire only uses hooks and I can't use the `useAuth` hook from ReactFire in the ErrorBoundary class component to get the accessToken.

I have tried to see if ReactFire exposes the firebaseApp singleton through ReactFire's API but have so far found nothing.

I have also tried retrieving the token from indexedDB in the browser but to do that you need the firebase private API to access it and therefore exposing that private key in the client.

I am still expecting/hoping to be able to get access to the firebaseApp singleton/instance through ReactFire somehow.

This is what the FirebaseApp provider looks like. Somewhere inside that `useFirebaseApp` I assume is the firebaseapp and accessToken I need but I can't get to it in my ErroBoundary class component.

the getAuth function from firebase also expects to receive the firebaseapp to return `auth` but that's wrapped up in the ReactFire hooks I believe, so I can't pass it anything.

Provider used in React for functional components

```
import { getAuth } from '@firebase/auth';
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import { AuthProvider, useAuth, useFirebaseApp } from 'reactfire';

export const useAuthenticateUser = () => useAuth().currentUser;

const FirebaseApp = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  return <AuthProvider sdk={getAuth(useFirebaseApp())}>{children}</AuthProvider>;
};

export default FirebaseApp;
```

ErrorBoundary class component

```
class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // geta=Auth is from firebase
    const auth = getAuth(useFirebaseApp); // can't do this in class component
    const auth = getAuth(FirebaseApp); // can't do this in class component

    const auth = getAuthTokenFromReactFire() // I want to do something like this
    const auth = getAuth(nonHookFirebaseAppFromReactFire)
}
```